# Pure CSS dropup-menu: I have the basics functioning, but how do I get the second-level li items to display inline instead of on top of eachother?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, vertical-scrolling

I'm using this: http://jsfiddle.net/fJSVz/ as my basic menu, and it's working fantastically for a bottom fixed menu. That said, I need to display the second-level list items that appear when you hover over the menu to be displayed ABOVE, CENTERED, and INLINE (on one line) instead of one-on-top-of-the-other. Any clue what I need to alter to get this to work? I'm tearing my hair out over this!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Dropup Demo</title>


<style type='text/css'>
   #navigation {
            width: 980px;
            height: 38px;
            margin-top:100px;
        }
            #navigation li {
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                width:100px;
                border:1px solid red;
            } #navigation li:hover { background: silver; }
                #navigation li a {
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    color: white;
                    padding: 13px 33px;
                    line-height: 38px;
                    font-size: 11px;


                }
                    #navigation li a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
                    #navigation li ul {
                        position: absolute;
                        display:none;
                        z-index: 1000;
                        min-width: 100%;
                        left:-1px;
                    }
                    #navigation li:hover ul {
                        bottom:20px;
                        display:block;
                        background:#eee;
                    }
                        #navigation li ul li {
                            background: none;
                            width: 100%;
                        }
                            #navigation li ul li:hover {
                                background: none;
                                background-color: #2a51b5;
                            }
                            #navigation li ul li a {
                                text-transform: uppercase;
                                color: white;
                                padding: 8px 10px;
                                line-height: 28px;
                            width: 100%;

                            }
</style>



</head>
<body>
<ul id="navigation">

<li>1</li>

<li>2
<ul>

<li>2.1</li>
<li>2.2</li>
<li>2.3</li>

</ul>
</li>

<li>3</li>

<li>4</li>



</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                   #navigation li  ul {
                        /*position: absolute;*/
                        display:none;
                        z-index: 1000;
                        min-width: 100%;
                        left:-1px;
                    }
```

Position `absolute` is the reason it makes the ul on top of the that .

Here is an fixed one http://jsfiddle.net/fJSVz/36/ .

Answer (score 1):

it can't be inline becouse its width=the width of  its parent width, so if you want them become inline, you need give te second ul width larger than its parent, then their li can be on one line..

so

```
    #navigation ul li ul{
width:400%; /*  in this case it will be 4*100px */
}

   #navigation ul li ul li{
display:inline-block
}
```

[here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/fJSVz/44/)

when parent is relative and the child is absolute, the child width can't be more than its parent, you need manualy put it larger.